# exponentiation question

Tags: exponentiation

I have a homework question on exponents, the question asks "simplify the expression and eliminate any negative exponents"

The Question is as follows
$$(2x^2y^4)^3(3x^{-3}y)^2$$

and my working out

$$=(8x^6y^{12})(9x^{-6}y^2)$$
$$=72x^0y^{14}=72y^{14}$$

is the answer correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right.  Technically, you don't need to eliminate the $x^0$ term as $0$ is not negative.